# Show fields in registration form

Tags: facebook

I try to use a facebook api to do sign up to my site with facebook accounts:

This is the code

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
        client_id=1845645421&
        redirect_uri=http://mysite.org/signup/
        fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
        scrolling="auto"
        fb_only="true"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="500px"
        height="330">
</iframe>
```

when i try with my account only my photo and user name appears not other fields i write in the code like birthday ! What is my wrong ?

Comment: You have written that src URL in one line though, and not with that much whitespace in between, right?

Comment: I write it as it appears above

Comment: I use XFBML instead of iframe and it works right